# Quick sort : analysis of partitioning

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm studying quick-sort in the course of Algorithms 4th, Robert Sedgewick.

I want to know the following partition of quicksort code's the number of compare in an array of length N.

```
private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
{
  int i = lo, j = hi+1;
  while (true)
  {
    while (less(a[++i], a[lo]))
      if (i == hi) break;

    while (less(a[lo], a[--j]))
      if (j == lo) break;

    if (i>= j) break;
    exch(a, i, j);
  }

  exch(a, lo, j);
  return j;
}
```

I want to know T(n) of code described above. ( compare )

In my thought, it takes ~2N compares.

The reason is because it takes N compares for `i` to move from left to right, and for `j` to move right to left respectively in an already sorted array such as an array (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H).

> compare = less()

Comment: what do you mean by `number of compare in an array` ?

Comment: is `number of compare` is referred to `if(i>=j) break;` statement?

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian only `less()`. Then what is the number of compares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of this partition function is `T(n) = O(n)`

Comment: In tilde notation (including constant), what is the T(n)?

Comment: It takes  ~N due to n compares.

Answer (score 0):

My god, it's my mistake in the iteration of `i`.

In the course of finding `i` to stop, that takes only 1 compares.

So, It takes ~N Compares.